# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST' (Android / Gradle)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to build my app and get the following error:

`More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'`

I am pretty sure it is a conflict between these two Gradle dependencies, but have no idea how to solve it.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-vision:1.99.1'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

add this line into app level `build.gradle` file in `android{}`

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For the latest **android modular architecture/multi module**

Please add this option part of the top module where the **application** class is present else it won't work.

```
packagingOptions {
     exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved by adding this into android{}

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
}
```